# CSV export from a powershell script

Tags: powershell, csv, export

I have a piece of code in powershell which I use as an "installation recipe".
I use this script to check that the preparation of the PCs is good and that the various software are installed correctly.
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force

```
If ((Test-Path "C:\Program Files\7-Zip") -eq $True) 
   {Write-Host " ~                 7-ZIP : Installation => OK!                  ~" -ForegroundColor Green}
else{Write-Host " ~                7-ZIP : Installation => NOK!                  ~" -ForegroundColor Red}
 
Sleep 3

If ((Test-Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC") -eq $True) 
   {Write-Host " ~             Adobe Reader DC : Install => OK!                 ~" -ForegroundColor Green}
else{Write-Host " ~            Adobe Reader DC : Install => NOK!                 ~" -ForegroundColor Red}

exit
```

If the installation is OK (OK), then it generates a value that we store and then export to a .CSV or .XLSX file. Ditto if the installation is not OK (NOK).

How do you do that?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Hashtable as shown in [VonPryz answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63935545/9898643) to collect the names and paths of the software to test is indeed the easiest way of dealing with this.

From the questions title,you would like a CSV file with the results of the tests; not only colored console output. For that, you need to loop through the list of software and output **objects** you collect in a variable like below:

```
# add as many items here as you would like to test
$software = @{
    "7-Zip"           = "C:\Program Files\7-Zip"
    "Adobe Reader DC" = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC"
}

# a template line for output to console
$message = ' ~ {0} : Install => {1}! ~'

# loop through the hashtable Keys
$result = $software.Keys | ForEach-Object {
    $installed = Test-Path -Path $software[$_]
    if ($installed) { $color = 'Green'; $success = 'OK' } 
    else { $color = 'Red'; $success = 'NOK' }
    # output to console
    Write-Host ($message -f $_, $success) -ForegroundColor $color
    # output an object to save as CSV
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        'Software'    = $_
        'Path'        = $software[$_]
        'IsInstalled' = $installed
    }
}

# output result to console as table
$result | Format-Table -AutoSize

# output result as CSV file
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\InstalledSoftware.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Output of `$result` on screen as Table:

```
Software        Path                                           IsInstalled
--------        ----                                           -----------
7-Zip           C:\Program Files\7-Zip                               False
Adobe Reader DC C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC        True
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! It's exactly what I wanted! You're the boss!

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to save each non-installed software's name into an array for later processing.

That being said, testing paths the way in question could be improved. Instead of typing paths here and there, store them in a collection for easy processing. A hashtable works fine. Like so,

```
$ht = @{
"7-Zip" = "C:\Program Files\7-Zip"
"Adobe Reader DC" = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC"
"FooApp" = "C:\Program Files\FooApp"
}
$failedInstalls = @()
    
foreach($key in $ht.keys){ 
    if(test-path $ht[$key] ) {
        Write-Host " ~ $key : Installation => OK! ~" -ForegroundColor Green
    } else {
        Write-Host " ~ $key : Installation => NOK! ~" -ForegroundColor Red
        $failedInstalls += $key
    }
}
$failedInstalls
```

What's done here is that software names and paths are stored in a hash table. So, one central location for all the paths. Then the collection is iterated and each missing software is added to `$failedInstalls` array. Changing number of software is trivial, it only requires change in the hash table - no need for `if(test-path...` statement for each piece of software.

As how to export array as an XSLX or CSV is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: I found this | Export-Csv -Path "C:\users\$env:username\Desktop\export.csv" -Force -NoTypeInformation but I don-'t know how tu use it.
Thanks for your help.